# laravel html dynamic form with two select boxes where select two is depend on select one

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I need an HTML dynamic form where I can add multiple table fields with two select boxes. Select box two however, depends on select box one. I wrote JQuery code for that which is working fine for first row but not working at all for second(newly added) row.

**My jquery code to add new row :**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript">

                $(document).ready(function(){
                var i = 0;
                console.log(i);
                $("#add").click(function(){
                i++;
                console.log(i);
                $('#inv_table').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><select class="form-control custom-select" id="product'+i+'" name="product_id"><option>Select Product</option>              @foreach($products as $product)<option value="{{$product->id}}">{{$product->product_name}}</option>@endforeach                   </select></td><td><input type="text" name="price[]" value=""/></td><td><select class="form-control custom-select" id="gst'+i+'" name="gst[]"><option value=""></option>      </select></td><td><input id="'+i+'" type="submit" name="remove" value="Remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn_remove" ></td></tr>')
                });
                $(document).on('click','.btn_remove',function(){
                var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
                console.log(button_id);
                $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();
                })
                });
                </script>
```

**My jquery code for dynamic select box:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $('#product').on('change', function(e){
                        console.log(e);
                        var id = e.target.value;
                        console.log(id);
                        $.get('ajax-unit/'+id, function(data){
                            console.log(data.tax);
                            $('#gst').empty();
                            $('#gst').append('<option value="data.tax">'+data.tax+'</option>');
                        });
                    });

                });

                </script>
```

Plz Help me....

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post your HTML or Blade view files

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  It is good practice to include as much information as possible.  In this story, you can really help the folks trying to help by providing a link to the code as a snippet and also describe in great detail what you are seeing, what you expect and what you may have tried.